# Backbone/Underscore _.each(...) doesn't seem to work according to docs

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

In this code...

```
_.each(this.photos, function(element,index,list) {
    console.log('element...');
    console.log(element);
    var photoView = new PhotoView({photo:element});
    self.$el.append(photoView.render());
});
```

`element` is the entire this.photos collection. Why is not just one photo element of the 10 in the collection?

EDIT: Here is my method that populates the photos collection....

```
loadPhotos: function(memberId) {
    var self = this;
    this.photos = new PhotosCollection([]); 
    this.photos.on('error', this.eventSyncError, this);
    this.photos.fetch({
        url: this.photos.urlByMember + memberId, 
        success: function(collection,response,options) {
            console.log('Fetch photos success!');
            self.render();
        }
    });
},
```

The collection loads with models just fine. In the Chrome console, I can see the collection of models. I'm not sure what's wrong. I cannot iterate the collection with any of the methods recommended by posters below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions! I would never have figured this out without all your advice above. So here was the problem...

In the parent view, this loads up photo records for a particular member...

```
loadPhotos: function(memberId) {
    var self = this;
    this.photos = new PhotosCollection([]); 
    this.photos.on('error',this.eventSyncError,this);
    this.photos.fetch({
        url: this.photos.urlByMember + memberId, 
        success: function(collection,response,options) {
            self.render();
        } 
    });
},
```

Still in the parent view, Backbone.Subviews uses this to call each child view when it renders. Note how I'm passing this.photos to the subvw-photos...

```
subviewCreators: {
    "subvw-profile": function() {
        var options = {member: this.member};
        // do any logic required to create initialization options, etc.,
        // then instantiate and return new subview object
        return new ProfileView( options );
    },
    "subvw-photos": function() {
        var options = {photos: this.photos};
        return new PhotosView( options );
    },
    "subvw-comments": function() {
        var options = {};
        return new CommentsView( options );
    }
},
```

This is in the subvw-photos child view. Note how the intialize is accepting the collection as a parameter. See this problem?...

```
initialize: function(photos) {
    Backbone.Courier.add(this);
    this.photos = photos;
},

render: function() {
    console.log('rendering photosview now...');
    var self = this;
    this.photos.each(function(element,index,list) {
        var photoView = new PhotoView({photo:element});
        $(self.el).append(photoView.render());
    });
    return this;
},
```

I was passing an object wrapping the photos collection in to initalize but then treating it like it was just a ref to the photos collection. I had to change the subvw-photos initialize to the following...

```
initialize: function(args) {
    Backbone.Courier.add(this);
    this.photos = args.photos;
},
```

Then of course all the other code magically began working :-/

Thank you again for your tips! You definitely kept me on track :-)

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `_.each` method incorrectly. The [underscore methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) needs to called directly on the collection:

```
this.photos.each(function(element,index,list) {
    console.log('element...');
    console.log(element);
    var photoView = new PhotoView({photo:element});
    self.$el.append(photoView.render()); 
});
```

Or you if want to use the `_.each` from you need to pass in the [`models` property](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-models) and not the collection object itself as the list:

```
_.each(this.photos.models, function(element,index,list) {
    console.log('element...');
    console.log(element);
    var photoView = new PhotoView({photo:element});
    self.$el.append(photoView.render());
});
```

Comment: The collection (or whatever it is) has no each method. See this screen cap from Chrome console [No each method](http://imgur.com/6NV6rp4).

Changed code to `this.photos.each(...`

Comment: Added the method that fetches photos to the OP. Do you see any problems in that code?

Comment: I cannot see any problems with the fetching... but how do you declared your `PhotosCollection`? In which method you have your `_.each`? Based on the chrome output the second version from my answer which uses `this.photos.models` should work, but again when have you logged it out, is which method? It can be that `this.photos` contains not what you would expect at the time when you try to call each on it...

Answer (score 0):

One should use `this.photos.each(function(elt, index, list){...})` instead of `_.each(this.photos,...)` because `this.photos` is not an underscorejs `_.chain` object.